# Self Joins - Difference between Queries? (SQL Zoo)

Tags: mysql, sql

I solved a problem, but I am having trouble understanding why one of my previous attempts is incorrect (it is producing unexpected results).

I've tried comparing all the subqueries independently of the main query to determine what is causing the difference, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Any help is appreciated.

## Context

[This is the webpage with the question in particular, scroll down to problem ten.](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Self_join)

[This is the reference on the database the exercise is working with.](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Edinburgh_Buses.)

### Prompt

Find the routes involving two buses that can go from Craiglockhart to Sighthill.
Show the bus no. and company for the first bus, the name of the stop for the transfer,
and the bus no. and company for the second bus.

**Hint**

Self-join twice to find buses that visit Craiglockhart and Sighthill, then join those on matching stops.

## Solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT to_craiglockhart.num, to_craiglockhart.company, to_craiglockhart.transfer_stop, to_sighthill.num, to_sighthill.company
FROM (SELECT stopa.name AS transfer_stop, a.company, a.num, stopb.name
      FROM route a JOIN route b ON (a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num)
      JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop = stopa.id)
      JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop = stopb.id)
      WHERE stopb.name = 'Craiglockhart') to_craiglockhart
JOIN (SELECT stopa.name AS transfer_stop, a.company, a.num, stopb.name
      FROM route a JOIN route b ON (a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num)
      JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop = stopa.id)
      JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop = stopb.id)
      WHERE stopb.name = 'Sighthill') to_sighthill
ON to_craiglockhart.transfer_stop = to_sighthill.transfer_stop
ORDER BY CAST(to_craiglockhart.num AS int)
```

## Incorrect Solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_bus.num, first_bus.company, first_bus.transfer_stop, second_bus.num, second_bus.company
    FROM (SELECT stopa.name, a.company, a.num, stopb.name AS transfer_stop
          FROM route a JOIN route b ON (a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num)
          JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop = stopa.id)
          JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop = stopb.id)
          WHERE stopa.name = 'Craiglockhart') first_bus 
    JOIN (SELECT stopa.name AS transfer_stop, a.company, a.num, stopb.name
          FROM route a JOIN route b ON (a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num)
          JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop = stopa.id)
          JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop = stopb.id)
          WHERE stopb.name = 'Sighthill') second_bus 
    ON first_bus.transfer_stop = second_bus.transfer_stop
ORDER BY CAST(first_bus.num AS int)
```

### Theory

The main difference between the two is that for the incorrect solution, I chose to designate the first stop as the initial stop and the second stop as the transfer stop, whereas in the correct solution, I reversed that.